# Swift - access variable outside function

Tags: swift

new here and new to coding (or at least trying!).  I've got what i imagine is a really simple question.  I had a look through the answer here [Accessing variable outside function in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47623201/accessing-variable-outside-function-in-swift) but I can't reconcile it to my own example (probably because I'm new to it sorry!)

Anyway.... this is my code, it's just trying to calculate how much change you get from buying x cartons of milk with x amount of money.  It's all working but at the end I want to print a summary using variables within the function (I guess there's some repetition/it's a bit pointless but I'm just trying to learn how you'd do this in theory!)

So... code is....

```
//here i'm setting the function to calculate the total 
//price (they are £2 each) and the change I'm due

func getMilk(howManyMilkCartons : Int, howMuchMoneyPaid : Int) -> Int {
    print("go to the shops")
    print("buy \(howManyMilkCartons) milks")

    let priceToPay = howManyMilkCartons * 2

    print("pay £\(priceToPay)")
    print("come home")

    let change = howMuchMoneyPaid - priceToPay
    return change

}

// here i'm setting the variables which inform how many milks
//i'm buying and how much money i'm using

var amountOfChange = getMilk(howManyMilkCartons : 2, howMuchMoneyPaid : 10)

print ("hello, your change is £\(amountOfChange)")
```

So, at the bottom, instead of my print statement with just amount of change, I want to do is (just for learning) something like

"HELLO YOUR CHANGE IS (AMOUNT OF CHANGE) FROM BUYING "X CARTONS OF MILK" WHICH COST "£X", AND YOU PAID WITH "X AMOUNT OF MONEY" (i.e use variables from within the function, outside of the function - if that's possible)

I know this is a massive noob question and may well be covered properly in the question I referenced but I couldn't really follow it to this example so sorry if that's the case!  Thanks for any help!

Comment: "use variables from within the function, outside of the function" You can't. They are declared inside the function. So they are temporary, and scoped within the function. If you want something outside the function, pass it out as part of the result, or (less good) declare it outside the function.

Comment: Might help you to read about scope: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch01.html#_scope_and_lifetime

Comment: thanks i read up on the link and that was really helpful thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`howManyMilkCartons` and `howMuchMoneyPaid` are local variables created by passing arguments to the function. You cannot access them outside the function body. However, in your case, all you want is to declare new two variables (or constants) with a scope outside of the function, to which you can assign your values and then use those as parameters:

```
// function is the same
func getMilk(howManyMilkCartons : Int, howMuchMoneyPaid : Int) -> Int {
    print("go to the shops")
    print("buy \(howManyMilkCartons) milks")

    let priceToPay = howManyMilkCartons * 2

    print("pay £\(priceToPay)")
    print("come home")

    let change = howMuchMoneyPaid - priceToPay
    return change

}

// declare your constants (or variables if you want) here:

let numberOfCartons = 2
let moneyPaid = 10

// use those constants as arguments to the function
var amountOfChange = getMilk(howManyMilkCartons : numberOfCartons, howMuchMoneyPaid : moneyPaid)

// and access them here as well
print ("hello, your change is £\(amountOfChange) after buying \(numberOfCartons) cartons of milk for \(moneyPaid) pounds")
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of looking at this.  If you want the information outside of the function, then it's likely (in a full program) that you want it as a coherent record of your purchase.

So, consider....

```
class MilkPurchase {
    let cartons: Int
    let paid: Int

    var change = 0
    var price = 0

    init(cartonCount: Int, moneyPaid: Int) {
        cartons = cartonCount
        paid = moneyPaid
        price = cartonCount * 2
        change = paid - price
    }

}

func purchaseMilk(howManyMilkCartons : Int, howMuchMoneyPaid : Int) -> MilkPurchase {
    // Other logic perhaps
    return MilkPurchase(cartonCount: howManyMilkCartons, moneyPaid: howMuchMoneyPaid)
}

let purchaseRecord = purchaseMilk(howManyMilkCartons: 3, howMuchMoneyPaid: 10)
print(purchaseRecord.change)
```

Comment: thank you so much for this - i tried this and it does make sense yes - i haven't got to 'init' in the course i'm doing but i read up on it and I can sort of see what's going on here - thanks!